How can the word topic be uncountable?
In these examples:

She was an excellent speaker, but I found her choice of topic strange.


...specifics of sentence structure such as the markers of topic and object and even the shape of the past marker.

the word topic is used without any article. To my knowledge the word topic must be countable.
The same with the word object in the second example.
Can you please explain why it's used without any article, in other words how can it be uncountable?

Lack of article does not imply uncountability.

Ok, but why is it then without any article?

You can use an article after 'choice', e.g. my choice of a car is electric, or you can choose to not use an article, your choice of hat is a good one Both are idiomatic.

Is it specifically about these two words (choice, markers) or it can be applied to a broader category of nouns? If it is the latter, is there some lists/grammar rules or something like this for these idiomatic cases?

The 'broader category'  of noun that you are seek may be 'countable nouns that can be used generally', which is very large. Possibly you might look at the topic (!) of Using Articles with Countable and Uncountable Nouns A countable noun always takes either the indefinite (a, an) or definite (the) article when it is singular. When plural, it takes the definite article if it refers to a definite, specific group and no article if it is used in a general sense.

Thanks for the link. "When plural...no article..." - then it would be topics I guess.

topic can be uncountable there because it refers to something that always accompanies a talk or presentation, or is always a feature of an utterance, and in such contexts, there is only one topic.
Compare:

The novel was a great read. The author's choice of title, Bored to Tears, is weirdly misleading.

Contrast:

I love pizza but your choice of toppings, pineapple and ham, are not to my liking.


I think I've read that novel, or at least started it. Didn't the film adaptation star Hugh Grant?

@MichaelHarvey Wasn't that Maldives Massage?

Did it have a happy ending?

As it recall, things were left hanging.

The expression choice of NP is perfectly idiomatic. Consider

Given the weather, I found her choice of outfit surprising.

And markers of NP is similar:

For a toddler’s welfare, it’s important to watch for markers of cognitive development.


I am not a native, so "idiomatic" sounds a bit vague to me. May be you can give me the grammar rules for such idiomatic cases so I can understand how to use it the right way?

Does NP stand for Noun Phrase?

'Perfectly idiomatic' means 'sounds correct and natural to a native speaker'. It's not the cases that are idiomatic, but the usage - choice of with a singular noun and no article.

Yes, 'idiomatic' means 'correct usage'. It's clear. What I am asking is not whether it's correct or not, but WHY it's correct. Is it about 'choice' only or there are other multiple similar nouns?

Your title specifies the word topic (though your body also mentions object). But the key here is not the complements (tooic and object), but rather the constructs in which they appear. As it happens, choice of followed by a noun admits count nouns, as in This dish comes with your choice of side, where side means “side dish.” There is no more compelling why than “because that’s how this scrap of English works.”

In the second example it's "markers". So it's not about "choice" only.

In your second example, marker of means essentially “marker that something is a (or the).” And the articles are omitted because the complements name general syntactic categories rather than specific instances. If it instead read the markers of the topic, that would suggest that different topics might have different markers.
